# Get counts by merge two collections with conditions in spring data mongodb data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections called advertisement & contains.
I need a count of contains that containState is "ACTIVE" & lastModifiedDate in current ongoing month for that advertisement.

Also I have a conditions on advertisement that adState is "ACTIVE".

```
advertisement document
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("1231321321321"),
    "adNumber":1
    "adState" : "ACTIVE"
    "company" : "companyABC",
    "address" : "123 new road",
    "agentName": "Agent_2"
    "lastpublish" : ISODate("2018-01-18T20:20:02.262Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:03:06.694Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-01-18T20:20:02.262Z"),
    "createdBy" : "yasa",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "System",   
}

    contains documents

{   

    "_id" : ObjectId("465465456456"),
    "adNumber":1
    "containId": 10
    "containState" : "ACTIVE",
    "title" : "Increase sales by 10%",
    "detials" : "buy this solution to incresce ur sale by 10%",
    "agentName": "Agent_2"
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-01-11T15:03:06.694Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-01-11T15:03:06.694Z"),
    "createdBy" : "yasa",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "System",   
}

{    

    "_id" : ObjectId("56565656555"),
    "adNumber":1
    "containId": 11
    "containState" : "IN-ACTIVE",
    "title" : "Land for sale",
    "detials" : "Land near water park for sale",
    "agentName": "Agent_2"
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-01-11T15:30:01.694Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-01-12T15:03:06.694Z"),
    "createdBy" : "yasa",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "System",   
}

{


    "_id" : ObjectId("56887423587"),
    "adNumber":1
    "containId": 12
    "containState" : "ACTIVE",
    "title" : "car for sale",
    "detials" : "BMW for sale",
    "agentName": "Agent_2"
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-01-11T15:45:01.690Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-01-11T15:45:01.690Z"),
    "createdBy" : "yasa",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "System",   
}
```

Give code example to merge this on spring-data, mongodb in java.

Also suggest best way get result Aggregation or map reduce

Aggregate query

```
db.advertisement.aggregate([
  {$match:{"adState": "ACTIVE", "agentName": "Agent_2"}},
  {$lookup:
   {
     from: "contains",
     localField: "adNumber",
     foreignField: "adNumber",
     as: "result_ad"
   }},
{$project:{result_ad:1}},
{$match:{"result_ad": {'$ne': []}}},  
{$unwind:"$result_ad"},
{$match:{"result_ad.containState" : "ACTIVE"}},
{$group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } }}])
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Please show us the code that you have and someone will help you from there. Is both the collection related to each other ? What is your expected output json ? Add all the  pojos that you use to get precise answer.

Comment: @Veeram I have written a mongodb query for this, I have no idea to with spring-data also i need to filter with on-going month. I have added mongodb aggregate query on question

Answer (score 3):

You can try below spring aggregation query in spring mongo 2.x and Mongo 3.4 version.

```
Instant startofMonth = LocalDate.now()
                .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() ).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Instant endofMonth = LocalDate.now()
                .with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth() ).atTime(LocalTime.MAX).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("adState").is("ACTIVE").and("agentName").is("Agent_2"));
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                from("contains").
                localField("adNumber").
                foreignField("adNumber").
                as("result_ad");
UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("result_ad");
MatchOperation matchOperation2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("result_ad.containState").is("ACTIVE").and("result_ad.lastModifiedDate").gte(startofMonth).lte(endofMonth));
CountOperation countOperation = Aggregation.count().as("count");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, lookupOperation, unwindOperation, matchOperation2, countOperation);
Integer results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, colname, Document.class).getUniqueMappedResult().getInteger("count");
```

Comment: this will be worked fine i guess but I am receiving a codec exception. but i have registered mongoclient with codec                       CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().register ("com.myapp.domain").build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(environment.getProperty("mongodb.uri"), MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry));
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( mongoClientURI);
return mongoClient;

Comment: I have created domain classes for Advertisement, Agent, Contains also currently adding DBref for agentName, so I made a change like this MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("adState").is("ACTIVE").and("agentName").is(agent));    //agent is object

Comment: Can you please update the post with all the details or better create a new question ? It's hard to guess what could be the issue. Steps to reproduce will help to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the mongo aggregate pipeline, you will be needing to get the count

steps

1. $match - match the ad id
2. $lookup - join with contains
3. $unwind - split array to individual doc
4. $addFields - field to check on on-going month
5. $match - filter non matching docs
6. $group - count the matches

you can translate it to `Java`, `Spring` and `MongoRepositories`

pipeline

```
db.advertisement.aggregate(
    [
        { $match : { "adNumber" : 1 } },
        { $lookup : {
                from : "contains",
                localField : "adNumber",
                foreignField : "adNumber",
                as : "cons"
            }
        },
        { $unwind : "$cons" },
        { $addFields : {
                monthMatch : { $eq : [ { $month : new Date() }, { $month : "$cons.lastModifiedDate" }  ] }
            }
        },
        { $match : { "cons.containState" : "ACTIVE", monthMatch : true} },
        { $group : { _id : null, count : { $sum : 1 } } }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Ok, i am trying on it, appreciate if u give guideline to match with spring-data with example

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/aggregation/ java documentation for aggregation